# Form URL change data POST

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have a URL:

```
http://domanin.com/search-result/?start=06%2F08%2F2017&end=06%2F09%2F2017&room_num_search=1&adult_number=1&children_num=0
```

And I have a Bootstrap form:

```
<form class="form-inline search-hotel-box">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label><span class="flaticon-time"></span></label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="checkin" placeholder="Check In" value="">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="checkout" placeholder="Check Out" value="">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label><span class="flaticon-door-key"></span></label>
    <select class="form-control">
    <option disabled selected>Rooms</option>
      <option value="1">1</option>
      <option value="2">2</option>
      <option value="3">3</option>
      <option value="4">4</option>
  </select>
    <i class="fa fa-angle-down"></i>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label><span class="flaticon-profile-1"></span></label>
    <select class="form-control">
    <option disabled selected>Adults</option>
      <option value="1">1</option>
      <option value="2">2</option>
      <option value="3">3</option>
      <option value="4">4</option>
      <option value="5">5</option>
  </select>
    <i class="fa fa-angle-down"></i>
  </div>
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Search Hotel</button>
</form>
```

How can I make a POST to that URL, changing the data of the URL? I don't know how it could be if I used PHP, or is it possible to use jQuery to do this? Would appreciate any help with this.

Comment: You can set the forms action to point to their page and keep the variable in the URL the same on your page. If you are submitting this through a non HTTPS site then the site you are trying to search on might not allow you to display the results.

Comment: @syfer How can I do that? The page does not have https

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So if you want to POST data to a particular webpage then you can do this using action and method attribute of form element as:

```
<form class="form-inline search-hotel-box" action="http://domanin.com/search-result/demo.php" method="POST">
```

You also need to provide name to all the different form fields as:

```
<input type="text" name="start" class="form-control" id="checkin" placeholder="Check In" value="">

<input type="text" name="end" class="form-control" id="checkout" placeholder="Check Out" value="">

<select class="form-control" name="room_no_search">

<select class="form-control" name="adult_no">
```

Now when anyone fills all the info and clicks submit then all the data will be posted to the URL that is provided in the action attribute.
If you want to sent data by appending in URL then use GET instead of POST.

The data which is sent can be easily retrieved using php as follows:

```
$var = $_GET['start'];
```

or

```
$var = $_POST['start'];
```